# MySQL HOUR(TIMESTAMP) considering timezone

Tags: mysql, timezone, timestamp

I have a table that contains a column of type TIMESTAMP (which is stored in UTC). My server is currently in timezone 'America/New_York'. I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE hour(time) > 5;
```

Which returns the expected output. I then want to change the server's timezone to something else (doesn't matter what) and I want to get the same output as when it was 'America/New_York'. Basically, I want a query that returns all rows where the hour of time in timezone 'America/New_York' is greater than 5, regardless of what the current server timezone is.

I know I could use:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE hour(convert_tz(time, @@session.time_zone, 'America/New_York')) > 5;
```

But I don't want to use variables (@@session.time_zone) because I want this SELECT to be included in a view and views don't support variables.

Is there a way to force a TIMESTAMP to be converted to a specific timezone regardless of the current server's timezone?

UPDATE: I found a way to create a function and then call that function from within the view:

```
create function getTimeZone() returns VARCHAR(50) DETERMINISTIC NO SQL return @@session.time_zone;
```

This works fine, but I feel like it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: Your question contains a pretty good answer (IMHO). I wouldn't call it a "hack" but a "workaround" due to a missing feature in MySQL.